# How do I create a slider that changes the main page content as well as the slider content and animates the transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

As the title says, i'm trying to achieve the following effect but unfortunately I have no idea where to start. Any advice or would be appreciated. Here's a crude paint image to illustrate what I want to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PssGA.png

A page that has the closest effect of this is found here:

http://www.squarespace.com/tour/weddings

as you can see the slider has a small animation based on which slide is transitioning to which and the main page content changes.

Comment: Your need, although easy, requires a lot of time and effort investment, as it requires a lot of code. All you ask is found on many places on the Web. You could browse w3schools.com, jQuery animations, CSS animation and JavaScript DOM. DO not expect people to invest their time and effort in this, while you have not invested any of your own time or effort.

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to tell me how to do it, just to point my in the right direction.

Comment: If that is the case and you do not want some ready-made code, you are on the right track. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend u to find a open source slider,
 download,
 read its documentation
 and build ur slider on it.
**dont forget to read the license, before you decide to work with that slider**
i have found one:
https://github.com/gilbitron/Lean-Slider

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use jQuery and CSS to have that effect, I have used code I previously used, so the effect is vertical, scrolling down. You can edit it to do your bidding. Sorry I had no time to comment on the code! To change the slider, you can change the buttons (or links) on each slide!

**HTML**:

```
<div id="one">
    <h2>Header One</h2><p>
    <a href="#one">One</a> - 
    <a href="#two">Two</a> - 
    <a href="#three">Three</a> - 
    <a href="#four">Four</a> - 
    <a href="#five">Five</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <h2>Header Two</h2><p>
    <a href="#one">One</a> -
    <a href="#two">Two</a> -
    <a href="#three">Three</a> -
    <a href="#four">Four</a> -
    <a href="#five">Five</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="three">
    <h2>Header Three</h2><p>
    <a href="#one">One</a> -
    <a href="#two">Two</a> -
    <a href="#three">Three</a> -
    <a href="#four">Four</a> -
    <a href="#five">Five</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="four">
    <h2>Header Four</h2><p>
    <a href="#one">One</a> -
    <a href="#two">Two</a> -
    <a href="#three">Three</a> -
    <a href="#four">Four</a> -
    <a href="#five">Five</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="five">
    <h2>Header Five</h2><p>
    <a href="#one">One</a> -
    <a href="#two">Two</a> -
    <a href="#three">Three</a> -
    <a href="#four">Four</a> -
    <a href="#five">Five</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();//stop the browser from jumping to the anchor
    var href  = $(this).attr('href'),
        oset  = $(href).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop : oset
    }, 1000, function () {
        location.hash = href;
    });
});
```

**Note that the CSS below is  *NOT* essential!**

**CSS**:

```
div {
    height : 500px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```